# Ruby - Google sheets file will not open after saving locally

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, google-api

I'm having an issue with opening an exported file from google sheets. My program consolidates QTY and SKU for selected items to a google sheets file from a local spreadsheet and then saves the sheets file locally, which then it should ideally attach that file to an email and send it. For some reason the program saves the file, but regardless of what format I save it in it is unable to be opened. I've tried xlsx and pdf so far. I'm not sure if the data isn't saving properly to the file or what the issue is, but I can see the correct data populates in the sheets file online- it's just the saving-it-locally part that I'm having trouble with. There are no errors returned upon running the program, however it does say "String" followed by Unknown Key: SameSite = none when executing.

Here is the code:

```
require 'bundler'
require 'google_drive'
require 'roo'
require 'google/apis/sheets_v4'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'
require 'mail'
require 'date'
Bundler.require

begin
def read_spreadsheet(file_path)
  spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(file_path)
  header = spreadsheet.row(2)
  data = []
  (3..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    data << row
  end
  data
end

def format_data_plain_text(data)
  formatted_data = ""

  data.each do |row|
    unless row['REORDER QTY'].to_i.zero? || row['AC SKU'].to_s.empty?
      sku = row['AC SKU'].to_s
      quantity = row['REORDER QTY'].to_s

      formatted_data += "#{sku}\t#{quantity}\n"
    end
  end
  formatted_data.to_s
end


def insert_data(file_path, formatted_data)
  session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("client_secret.json", GoogleDrive::Session::DEFAULT_SCOPE, timeout_sec: 300)

  spreadsheet_title = "Reorder Details"
  spreadsheet = session.spreadsheet_by_title(spreadsheet_title)
  worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheets.first

  first_empty_row = 1
  while !worksheet[first_empty_row, 1].empty? && first_empty_row <= worksheet.num_rows
    first_empty_row += 1
  end

if first_empty_row == 1
  worksheet[first_empty_row, 1] = "SKU"
  worksheet[first_empty_row, 2] = "QUANTITY"
  first_empty_row += 1
end

puts formatted_data.class
  data_lines = formatted_data.split("\n")
  data_lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
    columns = line.split("\t")
    worksheet[first_empty_row + index, 1] = columns[0]
    worksheet[first_empty_row + index, 2] = columns[1]
  end

  worksheet.save
end

def download_google_sheet(sheet_id, local_file_path)
  session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("client_secret.json")
  spreadsheet = session.spreadsheet_by_key(sheet_id)

  worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheets.first

  worksheet.export_as_file(local_file_path)
end

def process_order(file_path)
  order_details = read_spreadsheet(file_path)
  formatted_data = format_data_plain_text(order_details)

  insert_data(file_path, formatted_data)

  puts "Data inserted into Google Sheets."

  sheet_id = 'randomlettersandnumbers'
  local_file_path = 'path\to\output.xlsx'
  download_google_sheet(sheet_id, local_file_path)
  send_email(file_path)
end

def send_email(file_path)
    # Configure your email settings
    options = {
      address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 587,
      user_name: 'email@email.com',
      password: 'password',
      domain: 'domain.com',
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true
    }
    Mail.defaults do
      delivery_method :smtp, options
    end

    order_details = read_spreadsheet(file_path)
    formatted_data = format_data_plain_text(order_details)

    #Specify the email content
    mail = Mail.new do
      from    'email@email.com'
      to      'email@email.com'
      subject "Order Details:"
      body    "Hey Tim. Hope you're doing well! I just need to place an order for the following items:\n\nThis will be using Net Terms.\n\nPlease let me know if you need anything else from me! Have a great week!"
    end
    # Send the email
    mail.deliver!
end

file_path = 'path\to\origina\local\file\012224 COUNT.xlsx'
process_order(file_path)

end
```

Thanks in advance for your help with this one.

I tried to save the edited google sheets file locally after the program consolidated the data needed from my local spreadsheet. The intention was to have a processed order form saved locally from sheets and while a file is generated with my current code, it is unable to be opened for whatever reason. The error I get when opening he file is along the lines of "this file cannot be opened because the file format or extension is invalid."

Comment: [`GoogleDrive::Worksheet#export_as_file`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gimite/google-drive-ruby/GoogleDrive/Worksheet#export_as_file-instance_method) - *"Exports the worksheet to `path` in CSV format."* Your file is a CSV. change the extension to CSV and it will open. Whether or not this is what you want is up to you. Additionally wrapping all of your code in a `begin...end` is going to make things very difficult for you.

Comment: @engineersmnky Dude you are the man!!! I'm sorry if I have some really novice questions but I really just want to learn. You don't know what you don't know.

Comment: my question to you is, how can I save it as an excel sheet if that's what I want to do? Also how does the begin/end thing make things more difficult? It was my understanding that aspect could help with returning errors as a failsafe or something.

Comment: Export the [Spreadsheet](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gimite/google-drive-ruby/GoogleDrive/Spreadsheet) not the WorkSheet. e.g. `spreadsheet.export_as_file(local_file_path)`. Also I guess the `begin..end` does not technically matter since you are not rescuing any errors but in that case it is also useless. Finally Ruby is Object Oriented to its core, you will find that using this to your advantage will make things much simpler (e.g. create Class(es) that perform actions)

Comment: I noticed when I save it using the method described above, it does open correctly however it seems to have reiterated the formatted data more than once. It should consolidate to about 30 lines and it's like 300 something lines because it just keeps iterating. The csv version did the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it possible that the issue is you keep running the program and modifying the same spreadsheet? Its is very difficult to tell what is going on over all but it seems like that could be a possibility based on the loop in `insert_data`

Comment: @engineersmnky actually you know what you were right. I wasn't considering that it was pulling the most recent data from the google sheet file so I was just looking at the generated csv thinking what the heck is going on, but I realized that it was iterating over each time in the sheets file online which was then pulling that reiterated data into the generated file. Sorry!!! Common sense not so common.