# Ruby - Cannot save formatted spreadsheet locally

Tags: excel, ruby, axlsx, argument-error

I'm having an issue when trying to save a formatted spreadsheet locally to my computer.

The purpose of the program is to consolidate units to reorder based on a master spreadsheet and save it locally. The program should then attach the formatted spreadsheet to an email and send it.

The program seems to function without using AXLSX as far as sending the email goes, but when creating the method to save the spreadsheet using this gem, I keep getting the same error over and over stating "unknown regexp option: n (ArgumentError)"

Any help is appreciated as this is a really frustrating issue. I was initially able to insert the formatted data to a google sheets file, but then I ran into a bunch of issues trying to save the sheets file locally or as a temp file so I wanted to try going this route instead.

Here is the code for reference:

```
require 'bundler'
require 'roo'
require 'mail'
require 'date'
require 'axlsx'
Bundler.require

begin
def read_spreadsheet(file_path)
  spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(file_path)
  header = spreadsheet.row(2)
  data = []
  (3..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    data << row
  end
  data
end

def format_data_plain_text(data)
  formatted_data = ""

  data.each do |row|
    unless row['REORDER QTY'].to_i.zero? || row['AC SKU'].to_s.empty?
      sku = row['AC SKU'].to_s
      quantity = row['REORDER QTY'].to_s

      formatted_data += "#{sku}\t#{quantity}\n"
    end
  end
  formatted_data.to_s
end

def save_to_excel(formatted_data, local_file_path)
  Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
    p.workbook.add_worksheet(name: 'Reorder Details') do |sheet|
      sheet.add_row(['SKU', 'QUANTITY'])

      data_lines = formatted_data.split("\n")
      data_lines.each do |line|
        columns = line.split("\t")
        sheet.add_row(columns)
      end
    end
    p.serialize(local_file_path)
  end
end

def process_order(file_path)
  order_details = read_spreadsheet(file_path)
  formatted_data = format_data_plain_text(order_details)

  local_file_path = "new\spreadsheet\output.xlsx"
  save_to_excel(formatted_data, local_file_path)
  send_email(file_path)
end

def send_email(local_file_path)
    # Configure your email settings
    options = {
      address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 587,
      user_name: 'email@email.com',
      password: 'password',
      domain: 'domain.com',
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true
    }
    Mail.defaults do
      delivery_method :smtp, options
    end

    order_details = read_spreadsheet(file_path)
    formatted_data = format_data_plain_text(order_details)

    #Specify the email content
    mail = Mail.new do
      from    'email@email.com'
      to      'email@email.com'
      subject "Order Details:"
      body    "Hey Tim. Hope you're doing well! I just need to place an order for the following items. This will be using Net Terms.\n\nPlease let me know if you need anything else from me! Have a great week!"
      add_file local_file_path
    end
    # Send the email
    mail.deliver!
end

file_path = 'path\to\original\spreadsheet\012224 COUNT.xlsx'
process_order(file_path)

end
```

I tried using Axlsx to save the spreadsheet as well as using google-api to save to google sheets. I was able to update the google sheets file successfully using google-api, but then I couldn't get it to save locally to my computer, so I figured trying to work locally would be a more simple solution.

Comment: Please pick a question. Do you want help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77908143/ruby-google-sheets-file-will-not-open-after-saving-locally or the current one? Both approaches are different and continuing to ask different questions while posting all (or substantially all) of the same code without isolating an issue is not very helpful.

Comment: @engineersmnky You've answered my previous question successfully so thanks. I want to know the answer to both so by no means should you feel obligated to answer anything you don't feel like answering. Yes I'm aware they are different approaches and I'd like to know how to execute either of the two methods. Is it wrong to want to know more than one approach? I appreciate your help but I don't appreciate your demeanor.

Comment: I am sorry you inferred any kind of negative demeanor from my comment, which was merely intended to direct you towards asking specific questions. Your questions along with the code make it difficult to assist as they are fairly overwhelming and reasonably non specific. Please note the general guidelines: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sure I'll try to improve the way that I ask questions moving forward. I appreciate your patience and please consider this is only my third question on this platform, so forgive me for not totally understanding the ins-and-outs of what is expected. I thought providing more code would be less vague for the reader because it's in the context of the program itself, but I suppose that is not the case.

Comment: My specific question here is: How do I save the formatted spreadsheet locally after consolidating the requested data from the master spreadsheet? It's effectively the same concept but instead of saving the formatted spreadsheet locally from an online source like sheets, I want to eliminate the need to pull from sheets if it's more straightforward to just save an updated spreadsheet locally from a master spreadsheet.

Comment: It'd help if you trim out anything not explicitly related to the problem at hand. For example, the emailing part here is entirely extraneous. Let's focus on the spreadsheet issue. Do you know what line of code pops that exception? It's hard to tell if this is from your code, or from a library.

Comment: Hey @tadman, I believe the issue is coming from the save_to_excel method because when I comment that method out and anything referencing it, I do not get the error but of course the file is not saved locally as a result either.

Comment: Including a stack trace in your question might help us narrow it down. It's also worth checking that this isn't a known bug in the library, and that you're using the latest version.